# How to iterate each number in array and sum them with the other?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to sum every number in the database with the next numbers and save all results and show to blade

The result that i want to show in blade like this:
| Debit | Kredit | Jml |
| -------- | -------- |-----------
| 2000000  | 0        | 2000000
|          |          |  **2000000**
| 5000000  | 0        | 7000000
|          |          | **5000000**
| 4000000  | 0        | 11000000
|          |          | **4000000**
| 1000000  | 0        | 12000000
|          |          | **1000000**

**index.blade.php**

```html
<table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">TANGGAL</th>
      <th rowspan="2">NO. BUKTI</th>
      <th rowspan="2" width="120px">URAIAN</th>
      <th colspan="2">MUTASI</td>
        <th rowspan="2">Jlm S/D</th>
        <th rowspan="2">KETERANGAN<br>(Sisa Pinjaman)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>DEBIT</th>
      <th>KREDIT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
    <tr>
      <td style="border-bottom: hidden">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->tanggal)->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: hidden">{{ $item->no_bukti }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:left;border-bottom: hidden;padding-left: 5px">{{ $item->uraian }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom: hidden;padding-right: 5px">{{ number_format($item->jumlah_pinjaman,0,'',',') }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom: hidden;padding-right: 5px">0</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom: hidden;padding-right: 5px"></td>
      <td style="border-bottom: hidden"></td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:hidden"></td>
      <th colspan="2" style="border-right:hidden">JUMLAH :</th>
      <td style="text-align:right;border-right:hidden;padding-right: 5px">{{ number_format($q,0,'',',') }}</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;border-right:hidden;padding-right: 5px">101.303.387</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;border-right:hidden">-</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;padding-right: 5px">6.938.338</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**IndexController.php**

```js
public function index() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = LogsPinjaman::where([
            ['user_id', '=', $user->id],
            ['status', '=', 'approve']
            ])->get();
            
        return view('ajuan_pinjaman.index', compact('user', 'data'));
    }
    public function create() {
        return view('ajuan_pinjaman.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'tanggal' => 'required',
            'no_bukti' => 'required',
            'jumlah_pinjaman' => 'required',
            'uraian' => 'required'
        ], [
            'tanggal.required' => 'Tanggal wajib diisi',
            'no_bukti.required' => 'No. Bukti wajib diisi',
            'jumlah_pinjaman.required' => 'Jumlah pinjaman wajib diisi',
            'uraian.required' => 'Uraian wajib diisi' 
        ]);

        $data = [
            'tanggal' => $request->tanggal,
            'no_bukti' => $request->no_bukti,
            'jumlah_pinjaman' => $request->jumlah_pinjaman,
            'uraian' => $request->uraian,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ];
        LogsPinjaman::create($data);
        return redirect()->to('ajuan_pinjaman');
    }
```